# How do you compile OpenSSL for x64?

Tags: c++, c, windows, 64-bit, win64

After following the instructions in INSTALL.W64 I have two problems:

- The code is still written to the "out32" folder. I need to be able to link to both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the library on my workstation, so I don't want the 64-bit versions to clobber the 32-bit libs.
- The output is still 32-bit! This means that I get "unresolved external symbol" errors when trying to link to the libraries from an x64 app.

Answer (score 25):

To compile the static libraries (both release and debug), this is what you need to do:

1. Install Perl - [www.activestate.com](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads)
2. Run the "Visual Studio 2008 x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt" (Note: The regular command prompt WILL NOT WORK.)
3. Configure with
   perl Configure VC-WIN64A no-shared no-idea
4. Run: ms\do_win64a
5. EDIT ms\nt.mak and change "32" to "64" in the output dirs:

```
    # The output directory for everything intersting
    OUT_D=out64.dbg
    # The output directory for all the temporary muck
    TMP_D=tmp64.dbg
    # The output directory for the header files
    INC_D=inc64
    INCO_D=inc64\openssl
```

5. EDIT ms\nt.mak and remove bufferoverflowu.lib from EX_LIBS if you get an error about it.
6. Run: nmake -f ms\nt.mak
7. EDIT the ms\do_win64a file and ADD "debug" to all lines, except the "ml64" and the last two lines
8. Run: ms\do_win64a
9. Repeat steps 4 and 5
10. EDIT the ms\nt.mak file and ADD /Zi to the CFLAG list!
11. Run: nmake -f ms\nt.mak

Comment: It appears that the outputs are still named `*32.lib` (`libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll`). Are the names wrong or am I not following these instructions correctly?

Comment: "Visual Studio 2008 x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt" > where do I find this ? (I use VS 2015 of my side)

Comment: @NicoAD download and install Build Tools for Visual Studio https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#vstool-2017

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem this way, using the 1.0.1c source:

Add this block to `util/pl/VC-32.pl`, just before the `$o='\\';` line.

```
if ($debug)
    {
    $ssl .= 'd';
    $crypto .= 'd';
    }
```

Add this block to `util/pl/VC-32.pl`, just before the `if ($debug)` line.

```
if ($FLAVOR =~ /WIN64/)
    {
    $out_def =~ s/32/64/;
    $tmp_def =~ s/32/64/;
    $inc_def =~ s/32/64/;
    }
```

Then build all varieties:

```
setenv /x86 /release
perl Configure VC-WIN32  --prefix=build -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE
ms\do_ms
nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak

setenv /x64 /release
perl Configure VC-WIN64A --prefix=build
ms\do_win64a.bat
nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak

setenv /x86 /debug
perl Configure debug-VC-WIN32  --prefix=build -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE
ms\do_ms
move /y ms\libeay32.def ms\libeay32d.def
move /y ms\ssleay32.def ms\ssleay32d.def
nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak

setenv /x64 /debug
perl Configure debug-VC-WIN64A --prefix=build
ms\do_win64a.bat
move /y ms\libeay32.def ms\libeay32d.def
move /y ms\ssleay32.def ms\ssleay32d.def
nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Conan](https://www.conan.io/). It is very simple to install and use.

You can request the files ready for use. For example for Linux x64 or usage with Visual Studio 2012. Here a sample instruction:

`conan install OpenSSL/1.0.2g@lasote/stable -s arch="x86_64" -s build_type="Debug" -s compiler="gcc" -s compiler.version="5.3" -s os="Linux" -o 386="False" -o no_asm="False" -o no_rsa="False" -o no_cast="False" -o no_hmac="False" -o no_sse2="False" -o no_zlib="False" ...`

Answer (score 3):

At the time of writing this how-to the most recent version of OpenSSL is 1.1.1a.

Environment:

- Windows 10
- MS Visual Studio 2017

Prerequisites:

- Install [ActivePerl](https://www.activestate.com/products/activeperl/downloads/) - Community edition is fine
- Install [NASM](https://nasm.us/)

> Make sure both Perl and NASM are in PATH environment variable.

Compiling x64:

1. Open x64 Native Tools Command Prompt
2. perl Configure VC-WIN64A --prefix=e:\projects\bin\OpenSSL\vc-win64a --openssldir=e:\projects\bin\OpenSSL\SSL
3. nmake
4. nmake test
5. nmake install

> Step 4 is optional.

Compiling x86:

1. Open x86 Native Tools Command Prompt
2. perl Configure VC-WIN32 --prefix=e:\projects\bin\OpenSSL\vc-win32 --openssldir=e:\projects\bin\OpenSSL\SSL
3. nmake
4. nmake test
5. nmake install

> Step 4 is optional.

Answer (score 2):

According to the official documentation:

"You may be surprised: the 64bit artefacts are indeed output in the out32* sub-directories and bear names ending *32.dll. Fact is the 64 bit compile target is so far an incremental change over the legacy 32bit windows target. Numerous compile flags are still labelled "32" although those do apply to both 32 and 64bit targets."

So the first answer is no longer necessary.

Instructions can be found here:

https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#W64

Answer (score 1):

If you're building in cygwin, you can use the following script, assume MSDEVPATH has already been set to your Visual Studio dir

```
 echo "Building x64 OpenSSL"
 # save the path of the x86 msdev
 MSDEVPATH_x86=$MSDEVPATH
 # and set a new var with x64 one
 MSDEVPATH_x64=`cygpath -u $MSDEVPATH/bin/x86_amd64`

 # now set vars with the several lib path for x64 in windows mode
 LIBPATH_AMD64=`cygpath -w $MSDEVPATH_x86/lib/amd64`
 LIBPATH_PLATFORM_x64=`cygpath -w $MSDEVPATH_x86/PlatformSDK/lib/x64`
 # and set the LIB env var that link looks at
 export LIB="$LIBPATH_AMD64;$LIBPATH_PLATFORM_x64"

 # the new path for nmake to look for cl, x64 at the start to override any other msdev that was set previously
 export PATH=$MSDEVPATH_x64:$PATH

 ./Configure VC-WIN64A zlib-dynamic --prefix=$OUT --with-zlib-include=zlib-$ZLIB_VERSION/include --with-zlib-lib=zlib-$ZLIB_VERSION/x64_lib

 # do the deed
 ms/do_win64a.bat
 $MSDEVPATH_x86/bin/nmake -f ms/ntdll.mak  ${1:-install}
```

Answer (score 0):

The build instructions have changed since this question was originally asked. The new instructions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39247560). Note that you will need to have perl and NASM installed, and you will need to use the developer command prompt.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use MSYS+[mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net):

1) download and extract msys to C:\msys
2) download and extract mingw-w64 to c:\mingw64
3) run msys postinstall script. When it asks for your mingw installation, point it to C:\mingw64\bin
4) Extract an openssl daily snapshot (1.0.0 release has a bug). In the source dir run
configure mingw64
make
make check
make install
5) openssl is installed to /local/