# Error "error A2009: syntax error in expression" when building OpenSSL x64 static libs

Tags: windows, visual-studio, openssl, 64-bit, nmake

I need the static libs of Openssl. I followed the instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158232/how-do-you-compile-openssl-for-x64). The steps I did were as follows:

1. Run the "Visual Studio 2008 x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt".
2. Execute **perl Configure VC-WIN64A no-shared no-idea**
3. Execute **ms\do_win64a**
4. Edited **ms\nt.mak** and change "32" to "64" in the output dirs.
5. Execute **nmake -f ms\nt.mak**

After doing all this, I get an error on the 5th step:

```
Assembling: tmp32\md5-x86_64.asm
tmp32\md5-x86_64.asm(8) : error A2009: syntax error in expression
tmp32\md5-x86_64.asm(9) : error A2009: syntax error in expression
tmp32\md5-x86_64.asm(677) : error A2009: syntax error in expression
tmp32\md5-x86_64.asm(678) : error A2009: syntax error in expression
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC
\BIN\x86_amd64\ml64.EXE"' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
```

What is going wrong here? Or can anyone provide me a link to the static libs of Openssl that I can use in my Visual Studio 20005?

Comment: Showing us the lines 8-9 would be a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to this problem. Somehow, `nasm` wasn't installed in my machine. The error shown here also didn't say anything about nasm either.

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem too, and found out that Perl was too old. The following line in x86_64-xlate.pl did not generate "PTR", although the variable $PTR was set:

```
$func .= "  mov QWORD${PTR}[8+rsp],rdi\t;WIN64 prologue\n";
```

When I installed ActiveState Perl 5.16.3 it worked fine!

(I only had Visual Studio masm installed, I guess that with nasm the generated code would've worked, since nasm doesn't seem to need the PTR keyword).

Answer (score 0):

Seems Active sate is also old in my environment. I am not sure if I was using correct version of nasm but my ml64.exe was not compatible with nasm by command line parameters. People said I had to add asm variable into my environment.
So I did a global change in crypto\perlasm\x86_64-xlate.pl file:
"PTR}[" to "PTR} [".
Just added a space after variable.

Comment: How is this an answer to the original question?

Comment: asm files are generated by perl. There is an error in perl script. Variable is taken like an array instead to be just a variable. if you add an space in text variable it will produce correct 
"mov QWORD PTR [8+rsp],rdi ;WIN64 prologue"
instead 
"mov QWORD[8+rsp],rdi ;WIN64 prologue"
(PTR is missing) and you have error A2009 from the questions.