# Assembler errors with OpenSSL 1.0.2L and Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, openssl, masm

I am getting this error while building OpenSSL 1.0.2L on Visual Studio 2015 (32-bit):

```
Building OpenSSL
        ml /nologo /Cp /coff /c /Cx /Zi /Fotmp32.dbg\sha1-586.obj tmp32.dbg\sha1-586.asm
 Assembling: tmp32.dbg\sha1-586.asm
tmp32.dbg\sha1-586.asm(1432) : error A2071:initializer magnitude too large for specified size
tmp32.dbg\sha1-586.asm(1432) : error A2070:invalid instruction operands
tmp32.dbg\sha1-586.asm(1576) : error A2071:initializer magnitude too large for specified size
tmp32.dbg\sha1-586.asm(1576) : error A2070:invalid instruction operands
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\ml.EXE"' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
```

Comment: You have to use NASM. Stepping back, what procedure are you following? From OpenSSL's [`NOTES.WIN`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/NOTES.WIN): *"Note that NASM is the only supported assembler. The Microsoft provided assembler is NOT supported."*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when building OpenSSL x64 static libs on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546234/error-when-building-openssl-x64-static-libs-on-windows)