# Use Perl to download files from website that requires a p12 certificate

Tags: perl, lwp

I have a website that I need to download files from.  The website requires a digital certificate which I have.  I have a p12 file that the site provided which is very easy to import into Windows which allows access to the site.  What I want to do is download a bunch of csv files from the site and parse them.

I found the Net::SSLeay and Crypt::SSLeay packages.  I also see that LWP::Useragent has mention of SSL but I'm not sure if that is sufficient for what I'm trying to do.

So basically I need to know where to get started and which packages will be the easiest to use for this purpose.
I am running windows 7 with strawberry perl 5.16.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing you have your P12 converted into PEM format, you can use:

```
use Mojo::UserAgent;
my $url = 'https://some.site.com/path/to/file.zip';
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new( max_redirects=>5, 
                               cert=>'client_cert.crt.pem', 
                               key=>'client_cert.key.pem' );
$ua->get($url)->res->content->asset->move_to('downloaded_file.zip');
```

If you are using strawberry perl you need first to install Mojo::UserAgent module like this:

```
c:\> cpan -i Mojo::UserAgent
```

Answer (score 4):

Convert the [PKCS #12 certificate](http://enwp.org/PKCS12) to PEM format with the help of the [`openssl pkcs12`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs12.html) command. Install [LWP::Protocol::https](http://p3rl.org/LWP%3a%3aProtocol%3a%3ahttps). Set the [`SSL_ca_file` parameter](http://p3rl.org/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent#SSL_ca_file-path) to point to the PEM file.

Answer (score 1):

From this post it looks like to me that openssl supports 64bit linux since 2006:

http://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-users@openssl.org/msg47285.html

It could be possible to install it on Windows 64bit [How do you compile OpenSSL for x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158232/how-do-you-compile-openssl-for-x64)

So it is definitly possible to install it on linux. Please give us the error you have got.

Regards,

Comment: Sorry I took out the part of the question pertaining to OpenSSL until I'm sure I even need it for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: alternatively, install cygwin and use its openssl utility.

Comment: openssl utility is bundled with strawberry perl, just try to run "openssl" from command prompt