# Why is there no ms\do_ms.bat after perl Configure VC-WIN64A?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, openssl, activeperl

I'm compiling OpenSSL with Visual Studio 2015. I have installed:

1. Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10.
2. ActivePerl-5.24.0.2400-MSWin32-x64-300558.
3. nasm-2.11.08-win32.
4. OpenSSL source code by git clone git://git.openssl.org/openssl.git

What I did are:

1. Create a batch file with lines below.

   ```
   @call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64
   @set path=%path%;C:\Users\gchen\AppData\Local\nasm
   ```
2. `perl Configure VC-WIN64A —prefix=C:\test\openssl`

Now I should do `ms\do_win64a`, but I can't find this batch file. In the directory `ms`, there are files

```
2016/08/22  17:39    <DIR>          .    
2016/08/22  17:39    <DIR>          ..    
2016/08/21  14:23             3,646 applink.c    
2016/08/21  14:23             1,247 cmp.pl    
2016/08/21  14:23             2,815 segrenam.pl    
2016/08/21  14:23             4,541 tlhelp32.h    
2016/08/21  14:23             1,137 uplink-common.pl    
2016/08/21  14:23             1,472 uplink-ia64.pl    
2016/08/21  14:23             1,111 uplink-x86.pl   
2016/08/21  14:23             1,594 uplink-x86_64.pl   
2016/08/21  14:23             4,225 uplink.c   
2016/08/21  14:23             2,268 uplink.h
```

but there is no ms-win64a.bat.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer if it's correct for you?

Answer (score 41):

The build process has changed with the new 1.1.0 release. Probably you already figured out yourself, but anyway:

Starting with 1.1.0 there are no `ms\do_*.bat` files anymore.

Instead execute the following steps:

x32 compilation on Windows:

```
perl Configure VC-WIN32
nmake
nmake test
```

x64A compilation on Windows:

```
perl Configure VC-WIN64A
nmake
nmake test
```

Configure your Compiler environment as before and point your path to Perl (and NASM if used).

Source: The `INSTALL` file included in the 1.1.0 release.

Comment: As you said, I have figured out the problem. Your answer makes me feel good.

Comment: As you said, I have figured out the problem. Anyhow your answer makes me feel good.
At the beginning, I used Active Perl. I got warning saying that can't find nmake. But I know VC nmake.exe is in the PATH. 
I switch to StrawPerl, which works fine.

Comment: Make sure that you are running everything as Administrator

Answer (score 5):

Since the new 1.1.0 release there is no `ms\` folder in the source code. And if you wonder what should you edit to build a static version nowadays (which results in a single .exe file without any DLLs). Here is the full guide.

You will need the following prerequisites:

- Git for Windows. You can download it at https://git-scm.com/download/win. This guide uses [version 2.11.0.3](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.11.0.windows.3/Git-2.11.0.3-64-bit.exe).
- Strawberry perl. You can download it at http://strawberryperl.com/ (Warning: ActivePerl is highly not recommended. It **will** give you strange errors during the process). This guide uses [version 5.24.1.1](http://strawberryperl.com/download/5.24.1.1/strawberry-perl-5.24.1.1-64bit.msi).
- NASM assembler, which is available from http://www.nasm.us/. This guide uses [version 2.12.03rc1](http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.12.03rc1/win64/nasm-2.12.03rc1-installer-x64.exe).

You are expected to install all those tools system-wide and add them to your `%PATH%` environmental variable.

After you got everything we need, just follow this simple steps:

1. Open *VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt* from your Start Menu. You will see command prompt.
2. Create `C:\build` directory and issue the following command in the command prompt:

   - `cd c:\build`
3. Download latest zlib & OpenSSL source codes to your `build` dir by using the following commands:

   - `git clone https://github.com/madler/zlib`
   - `git clone https://github.com/openssl/openssl`
4. First we have to build static `zlib`. To do that first we will need to edit some configuration files:

   - Navigate to the `zlib` source folder: `cd C:\build\zlib`
   - Edit the `win32\Makefile.msc` file:

     1. Find the line starting with `CFLAGS`
     2. Replace `-MD` with `-GL -MT -Zc:wchar_t-`
     3. Find the line starting with `LDFLAGS`
     4. Replace `-debug` with `-opt:icf -dynamicbase -nxcompat -ltcg /nodefaultlib:msvcrt`
5. Build `zlib` using the following command (should take less than a minute):

   - `nmake -f win32/Makefile.msc AS=ml64 LOC="-DASMV -DASMINF -DNDEBUG -I." OBJA="inffasx64.obj gvmat64.obj inffas8664.obj"`
6. Copy resulting files to your `OpenSSL` directory:

   - `xcopy zlib.h C:\build\openssl\`
   - `xcopy zconf.h C:\build\openssl\`
   - `xcopy zlib.lib C:\build\openssl\`
   - `xcopy zlib.pdb C:\build\openssl\`
7. Navigate to `OpenSSL` source: `cd C:\build\openssl\` and configure it to use static zlib & read configuration files (`openssl.cnf`) from `C:\Windows\` directory.

   - `perl Configure VC-WIN64A no-shared zlib no-zlib-dynamic threads --prefix=C:\Windows\`
8. Now make the following edits to the `C:\build\openssl\makefile`:

   - Find the line that starts with: `CFLAG`
   - Append: `/Zc:wchar_t- /GL /Zi`
   - Find the line that starts with: `LDFLAGS`
   - Replace `/debug` with `/incremental:no /opt:icf /dynamicbase /nxcompat /ltcg /nodefaultlib:msvcrt`
   - Find the line that starts with: `EX_LIBS`
   - Replace `ZLIB1` with `zlib.lib`
   - Save changes
9. Build `OpenSSL` by issuing the `nmake` command (will take around 15 minutes).

The resulting ~3MB `openssl.exe` file will be located at `C:\build\openssl\apps\` directory. It is fully portable, since all DLLs are included. If you need to use custom configuration file, copy `C:\build\openssl\apps\openssl.cnf` to your `C:\Windows\` directory & edit it to your liking.

Comment: Great! You could also add a line for the "nmake install" part.

Answer (score 0):

The following commands need to be executed under the administrator user

1. perl Configure VC- WIN64A --prefix=C:\Build-OpenSSL-VC32-Debug-DLL
2. nmake -f makefile
3. nmake install

Starting with 1.1.0 there is no need of executed ms\do_*.bat files anymore.