# 'ms\do_win64a' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: openssl

I am compiling OpenSSL with Visual Studio 2012 on windows 10.
I have installed below :

- Visual Studio 2012
- strawberry-perl-5.38.0.1
- openssl-3.2.0

I am running below command :

```
       'cd to 'openssl-3.2.0' directory'
       ***perl Configure no-idea no-rc5 no-mdc2 no-threads shared VC-WIN64A &&  ms\do_win64a***
```

Getting blow error :

> 'ms\do_win64a' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Same is working correctly with "openssl-0.9.8i"

Please help me on this..

How to compile without any error

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076244/why-is-there-no-ms-do-ms-bat-after-perl-configure-vc-win64a helps?

Comment: Thanks, it is working if I changes command to "perl Configure no-idea no-rc5 no-mdc2 no-threads shared VC-WIN64A" But On next line I am getting error "NMAKE : fatal error U1052: file 'ms\ntdll.mak' not found" for command "cd C:\openssl-1.1.1w && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe" -f ms\ntdll.mak"