# Compiling static Qt for Windows can't open include file

Tags: qt, qt5.7, msvc14

I've been trying to get a static build of Qt 5.7 together so I can start compiling an application statically on Windows, but it's been a bit of a slog. I've got most of the process working - except it is complaining about not being able to include a file now that I can't see any reason for it to complain about.

I have to use MSVC (2015 is what is installed) and nmake because we're including webkit (which is possible with MinGW - and so we can't cross-compile from Linux either).

I've worked through and adapted the following sites (amongst others):

- http://amin-ahmadi.com/2016/09/22/how-to-build-qt-5-7-statically-using-msvc14-microsoft-visual-studio-2015/
- https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_Desktop_for_Windows_with_MSVC
- [How do you compile OpenSSL for x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158232/how-do-you-compile-openssl-for-x64)

My configure command:

```
configure -debug-and-release -commercial -static -ltcg -accessibility \
  -platform win32-msvc2015 -qt-sql-sqlite -qt-sql-sqlite2 \
  -plugin-manifests -no-audio-backend -openssl -no-dbus \
  -incredibuild-xge -sse2 -qt-style-windows -qt-style-fusion \
  -no-native-gestures -qmake \
  -I C:\devel\source\openssl\inc64
```

And right now it's complaining that it can't load "openssl\ssl.h" - except that this is available in `C:\devel\source\openssl\inc64\openssl\ssl.h`

Comment: ... `%PATH%` should not be considered *at all* when looking for headers. Instead, add the relevant `-I` and `-L` flags to configure, pointing at your OpenSSL installation.

Comment: @peppe I've now tried as you suggested - but still got the error

Comment: Any chance of getting the compiler's command line and checking that the right include paths were passed? I'm very suspicious about using \ in a shell. Perhaps they should be /.